# How to get rid of a white outline around header?

Tags: html, css

I created a header with `<div></div>` in html, but when I tested it there is a white outline around header. I created header in `<head></head>`.
Image of header: [header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW0sJ.png)

HTML code of my site:

```css
    .header {
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      background-color: skyblue;
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
  NetPlat
</title>

<head>


  <div class="header">
    <a href="login.php">
      <button style="float: right;">Logout</button>
    </a>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Remove margin from body

Comment: Also, `<head>` isn;t ment for elements like `div` that should be inside the `body`

Comment: @0stone0 Oh wow, I didn't know that browsers would even render content in the `head`. They always surprise me with something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something related to default browser styles. Basically, it is a set of styles that are added by the browser to the pages. A simple solution is to reset the margin, padding, and box-sizing like the following snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But for a larger scale website, I do suggest using josh wcomeau reset code snippet:

```css
/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
  2. Remove default margin
*/
* {
  margin: 0;
}
/*
  3. Allow percentage-based heights in the application
*/
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
/*
  Typographic tweaks!
  4. Add accessible line-height
  5. Improve text rendering
*/
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*
  6. Improve media defaults
*/
img, picture, video, canvas, svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
  7. Remove built-in form typography styles
*/
input, button, textarea, select {
  font: inherit;
}
/*
  8. Avoid text overflows
*/
p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
/*
  9. Create a root stacking context
*/
#root, #__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}
```

**Related Links:**

[josh advanced reset styles](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/custom-css-reset/)

Comment: And I can insert this into  `<style>`?

Comment: Yes. And I do recommend modifying these snippets to suit the engineering requirements and the UX/UI.

Comment: Also, when possible use external CSS. Please refer to this article as a reference [How To Add CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Answer (score 1):

It's related to your browser's default styling. So you can remove the margin from the body element:

```
body {
  margin: 0
}
```